# Multilevel Indexing with Groupby

Tags: pandas

Being new to python I'm struggling to apply other questions about the groupby function to my data. A sample of the data frame :

```
ID    Condition    Race      Gender      Income
1         1        White      Male          1
2         2        Black     Female         2
3         3        Black      Male          5
4         4        White     Female         3
...
```

I am trying to use the groupby function to gain a count of how many black/whites, male/females, and income (12 levels) there are in each of the four conditions. Each of the columns, including income, are strings (i.e., categorical).

I'd like to get something such as

```
Condition    Race       Gender     Income    Count
   1         White       Male         1        19
   1         White      Female        1        17
   1         Black       Male         1        22
   1         Black      Female        1        24
   1         White       Male         2        12
   1         White      Female        2        15
   1         Black       Male         2        17
   1         Black      Female        2        19
  ...
```

Everything I've tried has come back very wrong so I don't think I'm anywhere near right, but I"m been using variations of

```
Data.groupby(['Condition','Gender','Race','Income'])['ID'].count()
```

When I run the above line I just get a 2 column matrix with an indecipherable index (e.g., f2df9ecc...) and the second column is labeled ID with what appear to be count numbers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would investigate the  resulting dataframe you would see that the columns are inside the index so just reset the index...

```
df = Data.groupby(['Condition','Gender','Race','Income'])['ID'].count().reset_index()
```

that was mainly to demonstrate but since you what you want you can sepcify the argument 'as_index' as following:

```
df = Data.groupby(['Condition','Gender','Race','Income'],as_index=False)['ID'].count()
```

also since you want the last column to be 'count' :

```
df = df.rename(columns={'ID':'count'})
```

Comment: Wow, so it was that easy. I don't quite understand why, though. Was it trying to cram every variable into the index column ?

Comment: you should meet `groupby` magics and dive into pandas little further, good luck and thanks for accepting my answer!